# Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError) when declaring variable for factorygirl.create(:user) in another factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Here is a piece of confusion for me right here:

I have a factory for users as:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email     { Faker::Internet.email }
    password  { Faker::Internet.password }
    name      { Faker::Name.name }
  end

end
```

and then, I am trying to create a user in another factory definition as follow:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  factory :order do
    user                  { user }
    status                1
    delivery_preferences  { "#{Faker::Address.street_address}, #{Faker::Address.city}." }
    instant_delivery      false
    status_changes        ["#{rand(5)}, #{Time.now}"]
    order_products_ids    { user.cart.order_products_ids[0..rand(3)] }
  end

end
```

but I keep getting an error that:

> Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)

I definitely am doing something wrong, but I really can't see it.  I need some extra pair of eyes here, haha. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the association improperly - using `user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)` basically does not work since the user factory is not guaranteed to be declared when you are defining your factory.

Also even if this works than all the factories would share the same User record since the variable is created in scope of the factory definition - not the block which is run when FG initializes a record.

This is how you would declare the association:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :order do
    user # FactoryGirl does lazy loading when the factory is used
    status                1
    delivery_preferences  { "#{Faker::Address.street_address}, #{Faker::Address.city}." }
    instant_delivery      false
    status_changes        ["#{rand(5)}, #{Time.now}"]
    order_products_ids    { user.cart.order_products_ids[0..rand(3)] }
  end
end
```

- http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations

Comment: and the `user` in `{ user.cart.order_products_ids[0..rand(3)] }` will be the same as the `order.user`?

Comment: Well every time you use `FactoryGirl.create(:order)` it will create an separate associated user unless you explicitly pass a user `FactoryGirl.create(:order, user: user)`.